# why r2_score is quite different between train_test_split and pipeline cross_val_score?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I wonder why r2_score is quite different between train_test_split and pipeline cross_val_score? I suspect it's because the model can see the unknown words through CountVectorizer() in the pipeline. But based on concept of Pipeline, CountVectorizer() should only work on training set split by cross_val?

```
pipe=Pipeline([('Vect', CountVectorizer()), ('rf', RandomForestRegressor(random_state=1)) ])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test=train_test_split(df['X'], df['price'], shuffle= False, test_size=0.5)

reg=pipe.fit(X_train,y_train )
mypred= reg.predict(X_test)
r2_score(mypred, y_test)
# result is -0.2
cross_val_score(pipe,df['X'], df['price'],cv=2)
# result is about 0.3
```

Comment: Do you still have this issue when setting shuffle = True in your train_test_split?

Comment: I set shuffle =False intentional to make those two case comparable. when shuffle= True (default), also very different results

Comment: Can you also try with cv = KFold(n_splits = 2) instead of cv = 2? As such, your examples are not comparable

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I replaced with KFold as you suggested. Big difference still exist

Answer (score 2):

```
r2_score(mypred, y_test)
```

is wrong.

You need to provide the true values as first input and predicted values as second. Correct that to:

```
r2_score(y_test, mypred)
```

and then check results.

Comment: Thanks so much!! This is exactly the problem. Many thanks!

Comment: Than you so much, again!